# Как вернуть текст с ссылками в боте Telegram?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Использую pyTelegramBotApi. Такая проблема: мне нужно, чтобы бот вернул текст пользователя обратно, при этом сохраняя ссылки.

```
@bot.message_handler()
def text(message):
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

Вот так не катит, он отправляет мне тот же текст, но без ссылок. Казалось бы, проблема вроде легкая, но очень долго ломаю голову над ней. Помогите, пожалуйста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно попробовать напечатать print сообщение и посмотреть ссылки, а после встроить их.

Comment: @Utsiye, нет, это выводит в консоль всю информацию о сообщении, включая ссылки, да. Но так встраивать в нужные места ссылки: непонятно как-то. Хотелось бы найти более тривиальное решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это

```
bot.copy_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id, from_chat_id=message.chat.id)
```

Первый `chat_id` это куда вы хотите скопировать сообщение

Answer (score 0):

Вернуть ссылку библиотекой telebot никак не выйдет, пробуй телетон/пирограм.